# Compile subset of dependencies into my jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a project with multiple Maven dependencies and want to minimize the size of my compiled JAR. Right now it seems that IntelliJ is compiling all of the external dependency source files into my JAR even though I only use a small subset of their functionalities.

I would like to include only the files that are directly used by my module.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dependency as optional:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>small-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- Will be packaged in JAR -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>really-big-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Another approach is to use the `provided` scope. The difference is `provided` is used if you know the dependency will be included in the classpath of the application that will run your JAR (e.g. a Web or Java EE container):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>small-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- Will be packaged in JAR -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>really-big-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- Will not be packaged in JAR, needs to be provided in classpath at runtime -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Sources:

[Maven - Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

[Maven - Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)